# Parallax quirk with Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have horizontal parallax div that displays a very wide image (3000px) and as you move the pointer left or right the image slides in the opposite direction.  It works great except in Chrome.

When the page is loaded into Chrome for the first time the image follows the pointer instead of going in the opposite direction.  If I reload (F5) it is still the same problem, HOWEVER, if I reload from the address bar with the URL it works perfectly.  I have tried everything that I can think of.

Comment: So… what's the question?

Comment: Live site, code sample, anything? Sort of impossible to figure out without anything to work with.

Comment: The question is "Why does the page need to be loaded twice before the parallax will work correctly?"  The problem is only with Chrome.